# Get MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().nextTrackCommand to work from UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm using this line to show\hide button in the lock screen.

If work perfectly if I put the lines on the appdelegate, but not in the viewcontroller.

Any idea?

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: "emptyForAudio")


MPRemoteCommandCenter.sharedCommandCenter().nextTrackCommand.enabled = true;
```

(i've try this, and it return true)

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable receiving interactions `UIApplication().sharedApplication.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` in `viewDidAppear` then become first responder.

And in `viewWillDissapear` stop receiving remote events `UIApplication().sharedApplication().endReceivingRemoteControlEvents` and resign first responder.